# UIWebView not displaying anything iOS App

Tags: ios

I want to view a url in web view, when I load the page, nothing shows on the screen

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.teamtreehouse.com"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

I already fixed the `NSAppTransportSecurity` issue in the .plist file. What could be happening

Comment: Is you webView allocated before or its IBOutlet set before?

Comment: I don't get what you mean! please elaborate

Comment: What is self.webView? Is this IBOutlet or class instance variable? If class instance variable, then alloc init it like:- self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init]; and set its frames.

Comment: are you using Xcode 7 ?

Comment: self.webView is IBOutlet and i'm using xcode 7

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine on my end. http://gph.is/1ZkcNfk
You can try to restart the simulator, a hack, may works for you.

Comment: Have you connected your webview outlet to the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, that's where the problem came from. I did it but it had be disconnected and I didn't know it. I've now reconnected it and worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: happy to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle UIWebView delegate to debug. You should also print webview 's frame. Maybe it loads but it's not visible on screen. Handle delegate is the best way to know it.

Comment: can you show me some code to do this, i'm a beginner in iOS

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.teamtreehouse.com"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView setDelegate:self];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(nullable NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFailLoadWithError: %@", error);
}
```

And for sure, you must connect your webView property to storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can print a `frame` of `webview` like this

```
NSLog(@"my Webview Frame is:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(mywebview.frame));
```

And you can set `delegate` like this

```
mywebview.delegate=self;
```